# What does this 1970s punched-card format mean?

Tags: punched-cards, fortran

The [1974 Texas Regional Programming Contest](https://icpc.global/worldfinals/problems/1974%20ACM-ICPC%20World%20Finals/1974-Texas.pdf) (a predecessor of the [ICPC](https://icpc.global/worldfinals/problems)) describes an input format:

> A room description will be contained on a single card with the format: `(1X, I2, 2X, 12 (A1, I2, 2X))`.
>
> The "number of corners" will be contained in columns 2 and 3 of the card and successive direction-distance pairs will be contained in columns 5-7, 10-12, 15-17, etc.

(I assume that the `12` is a typo and should be another `I2`.)

What does the format mean? What do `1X` etc. and `I2` denote?

Comment: No, 12 is 12.  It's a repeat factor.

Comment: See page 41 onwards in [this IBM FORTRAN II manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/fortran/F28-8074-3_FORTRANII_GenInf.pdf).A 1974 programmer would likely be using FORTRAN IV, but the particular format in your question looks valid for FORTRAN II as well.

Comment: The most mind-boggling thing about this is that *Texas had a college programming contest* ***in 1974*** when as far as I could find, there were only three universities in the country that offered an undergraduate programs with a major in CS (and none were in Texas).  (most offered minors, however)

Comment: @RBarryYoung - you don't need to be in CS to program, and many would say real CS has little to do with writing a program.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I know, I was a programming in 1974, in high school. That wasn't my point.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - fair enough, but there was lots of computer programming going on at universities whether there was an official Computer Science degree or not. Lots of science and engineering courses used programming to solve their problems.

Comment: @RBarryYoung There's a big difference between CS (theory) and programming (application).  There might not have been a lot of people studying, e.g., compiler design but there were/are a lot of people writing software as part of their regular work (scientists, engineers).  This was especially true in 1970s Texas (think Johnson Space Center, TI and other Silicon Prairie firms, oil exploration, etc.).

Comment: @JonCuster  But it's profile was exceptionally low and generally viewed as esoteric.  And there sure as heck weren't many state govt. sponsored college programming contests because I sure as heck would've entered them if I had known.  In fact, until I saw this, I would've said that there were *none*.  It is uncommon for states to sponsor inter-college activities (as opposed to high schools), and I sure neve would've picked Texas as the forerunner for this.

Comment: @JonCuster RE: "*There's a big difference between CS (theory) and programming (application)*" Not in undergraduate courses in 1974 there wasn't, I can promise you that.  I do take your point wrt Johnson Space Center and TI though, that seems like the most likely source for something like this in Texas.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - indeed, an interesting history question. I would suspect that the combination of UT Austin, Texas A&M, and Texas Tech probably spearheaded it, and the entities AlexHajnal pointed out got on board since they needed people with programming skills.

Comment: @JonCuster You know I'm only assuming that it was state-sponsored.  Maybe it was actually sponosored by Johnson Space Center and/or TI?  That would make *a lot* more sense.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - it could still well be state sponsored, but pushed by the various state university systems. Unlikely a legislator would come up with the idea out of the blue...

Comment: *The ICPC traces its roots to a competition held at Texas A&M in 1970 hosted by the Alpha Chapter of the UPE Computer Science Honor Society* – [ICPC Fact Sheet](https://icpc.global/worldfinals/pdf/Factsheet.pdf)

Comment: Independent of any relationship between software development and computer science: Is it conceivable that a university could teach its students some useful skill if they don't have a whole department and a degree program centered on that skill? I honestly don't know the answer today, but back in 1974, I'm pretty sure the answer was, "Yes."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, of course, CS was offered as a minor at many colleges and universities (including the one that I went to in 1975).  But "minor-only" studies don't usually get intercollegiate leagues which are expensive things requiring substantial sponsorship.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Thanks for that.  WOW, the UPE started at Texas A&M in ***1967***.  I am impressed.  Sure wish I had know about it back then.

Comment: I too can testify that in 1974, there wasn't a lot of distinction between computer programming and computer science as far as UK undergraduate degree courses went.  If you wanted to study "computers", the degree was called "computer science".  Your choices were whether (depending on university) it was offered by the School of Mathematics or the School of Engineering.

Comment: @SolomonSlow -  *relationship between software development and computer science:*.   I'd say also that computer programming and software development are different things.  This was a programming contest, not a software development contest.

Comment: @another-dave, Well, if you want to be strictly "retro" about it, then the "software" means the operating system (i.e., it's the part of the computer that isn't hardware.) Everything else—all the application-specific stuff that the end-user runs on it—is "programs."

Comment: @SolomonSlow - No, I mean that "software development" is basically doing programming in industry.  There's a whole lot more "process" involved.  But that may be modern usage.

Comment: @another-dave I promise you that there was no such distinction between *computer programming and software development* at the time.  In fact there was hardly any distinction between "programming" and "IT" either (though it was more often called "MIS" or "IS" back then).

Comment: @another-dave, I'm actually trying to agree with you. (even though it's hard for me to be agreeable sometimes.) When people ask me what I do for a living, I didn't start answering, "software _developer_" until some time in the 2000s. Prior to that, I'd say, "software engineer;" and prior to 1990 or so, I mostly said, "computer programmer."

Comment: @SolomonSlow - I'm a "programmer", definitely not a "coder" (them's fightin' words), not a "developer" (they put up buildings, often shoddy - so I suppose there's some connection there), and not an "engineer" (most programming isn't and shouldn't be engineering).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The symbols are as follows:

- `(`…`)` are used for grouping.
- `X` → Value doesn't matter
- `I` → Numeric (integer)
- `A` → Alphabetic (in this case one of `N`, `S`, `E`, or `W`)
- `,`  → Used to separate each column or group definition

The numbers indicate how many columns the field takes up or how many times the group is repeated.

Given the desciption `(1X, I2, 2X, 12 (A1, I2, 2X))` here's how it breaks down:

| Column | Description | Contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `1X` | (don't care) |
| 2 – 3 | `I2` | Corner count (2-digit integer) |
| 4 – 5 | `2X` | (don't care) |
| 6 | `A1` | Direction #1 (single letter) |
| 7 – 8 | `I2` | Length #1 (2-digit integer) |
| 9 – 10 | `2X` | (don't care) |
| 11 | `A1` | Direction #2 (single letter) |
| 12 – 13 | `I2` | Length #2 (2-digit integer) |
| 14 – 15 | `2X` | (don't care) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 60 | `A1` | Direction #12 (single letter) |
| 61 – 62 | `I2` | Length #12 (2-digit integer) |
| 63 – 64 | `2X` | (don't care) |

(The outer parentheses represent the entire card.)

---

The `12` that you premise is a typo is actually the repeat count for the definition of the list of corners.  In other words there is space allocated for 12 corner points on a card.  The actual number of corner points present on a given card is given in the first field (`I2` → a 2-digit integer stored in columns 2 – 3).

Comment: This answer is thorough.  It's worth adding that this format description comes from FORTRAN.

Comment: Interestingly, there _is_ a typo/mistake in the original document: "_in columns 5-7, 10-12, 15-17, etc._" should be "_in columns 6-8, 11-13, 16-18, etc._" as the above table shows.

Comment: @TripeHound typical "do we start counting at 0 or 1" error...

Comment: @Arsenal Seems unlikey... punched cards were always columns 1..80, and they say the corner count is in columns 2 and 3 (which would be 1and 2 if counting from zero). I think it's "just an error".

Comment: "Premise" should be "surmise."

Answer (score 4):

X is "space", prefixed by count, I is "integer", postfixed by the number of digits, A is "character", postfixed by character count, parentheses group items, a number before the parentheses indicates a repeat count. There is no typo.

Therefore, a line satisfying the format will be, for example,

```
 12  A23  B34  C45  D56  E67  F78  G89  H90  I01  J13  K24  L35
```

Comment: X is space on output, but skip on input.

Comment: @another-dave Skipped positions are typically filled with spaces in actual input for clarity.

Comment: Or "it's on the data card but this particular program doesn't care about it".

Answer (score 2):

Using the example measurements, a data card would look like:

[image: floor corners punched card data]

or as a line of text (with ruler added to help with column count):

```
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
  6  N 9  E16  N 4  E 7  S13  W23  N 0  N 0  N 0  N 0  N 0  N 0
```

This line was generated from the FORTRAN code

```
      PROGRAM corners
      INTEGER LENGTHS(12), KOUNT
      CHARACTER*1 DIR(12)
      DATA KOUNT/6/
      DATA LENGTHS/9, 16, 4, 7, 13, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0/
      DATA DIR/'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'W', 
     *         'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'/
      WRITE(UNIT=*, FMT=100) KOUNT, (DIR(I), LENGTHS(I), I=1,12)
      STOP
  100 FORMAT (1X, I2, 2X, 12 (A1, I2, 2X))
      END
```

Format line 100 is the format you asked about.

(card image generated by [Virtual Card Read-Punch](https://www.masswerk.at/card-readpunch/))

Comment: Just for my curiosity, what version of FORTRAN is that?  Specifically, with the keywords in the WRITE.  (I stopped using FORTRAN in the mid-70s, so 66 was the last standard I cared about)

Comment: Fortran 77, though [IBM 7030 FORTRAN IV](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibm7030C22y63_3354999/page/n9/mode/2up?q=READl+%28) had that feature in 1963. DEC even managed to squeeze it into the PDP-8 FORTRAN-IV